# Input type='number' event keyup and keydown

Tags: jquery

I try to create a event for a input type number. It is on basket page and if the user clicks on button UP it have to change price and down also. It works fine if it is only one item in basket. But if it is 2 or more then it's works not as it have to do.

```js
$("input[type=number]").bind('keyup input', function() {
  var wrapper = $(this).closest(".quantety");
  var quantety = wrapper.find('.inputQuantity').val();
  alert("quantety = " + quantety + " quantetyNumber = " + quantatyNumber);
  if (quantety > quantatyNumber) {
    quantatyNumber = quantatyNumber + 1;
    var summaplus = wrapper.find('.inputQuantity').attr('id');
    var totalPlus = wrapper.find('.penger').text();
    totalPlus = parseInt(totalPlus);
    summaplus = parseInt(summaplus);
    var total = totalPlus + summaplus;
    $('.penger').text(total);

    var summaUp = $('.summa').text();
    summaUp = parseInt(summaUp);
    var Plus = summaUp + summaplus;
    $('.Geld').text(Plus);
    $('.summa').text(Plus);
  } else if (quantety < quantatyNumber) {
    alert('Test-2');
    quantatyNumber = quantatyNumber - 1;
    //var wrapper = $(this).closest(".basDiv");
    var summaminus = wrapper.find('.inputQuantity').attr('id');
    var totalMinus = wrapper.find('.penger').text();
    totalMinus = parseInt(totalMinus);
    summaminus = parseInt(summaminus);
    var Minus = totalMinus - summaminus;
    $('.penger').text(Minus);
    //
    var summaDown = $('.summa').text();
    summaDown = parseInt(summaDown);
    var total = summaDown - summaminus;
    $('.Geld').text(total);
    $('.summa').text(total);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='basketmain'><br>
  <h2>Varorkorg</h2>
  <div class='basDiv'>
    <img src='img/4.jpg' class='basIMG' alt='Taklampa Arma' />
    <div class='ProductName'>
      <p class='Pname'>Taklampa Arma</p>
    </div>
    <div class='itemLink'><a href='#' class='ProductLink'>Taklampa Arma</a>
    </div>
    <div class='quantety'>
      <input type='number' class='inputQuantity' id='254' value='1' min='1' />
    </div>
    <div class='ProductPrice'>Pris: <span class='penger'>254</span> kr
    </div>
    <div class='removeItem'><img src='img/remove.png' class='removeItemImg' alt='Radera'>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='basDiv'>
    <img src='img/5.jpg' class='basIMG' alt='Taklampa Igor'>
    <div class='ProductName'>
      <P class='Pname'>Taklampa Igor</p>
    </div>
    <div class='itemLink'><a href='#' class='ProductLink'>Taklampa Igor</a>
    </div>
    <div class='quantety'>
      <input type='number' class='inputQuantity' id='123' value='1' min='1' />
    </div>
    <div class='ProductPrice'>Pris: <span class='penger'>123</span> kr
    </div>
    <div class='removeItem'><img src='img/remove.png' class='removeItemImg' alt='Radera'>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="DivSumma">
    <div class="PayButton">
      <form action="" method="POST">
        <input type="submit" value="Betala" id="PayItem" />
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="TotalSumma">Att Betala <span class="summa">377</span> kr
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Variable quantatyNumber  is global to look if the value of input on click is bigger or not. is it possible to fix my problem on easy way?

A div block with class '.Geld' is in my header.

Comment: There's doesn't appear to be any code that checks if the user has pressed the up key (I'm assuming up key rather than an 'up button' as you mention keyup/down event and there's no button in the html)

Answer (score 0):

I will not create one more ask. Now i have change the input type number to input type text and added two images, and created two function for each of image on click function. look code down.

```
$('.qantetyImgPlus').on('click', function(){
    var wrapper = $(this).closest(".basDiv");
        quantety = wrapper.find('.inputQuantity').val();
        quantety = parseInt(quantety);
        if(quantety >= 1){
            var quantatyNumber = quantety + 1;
            $('.inputQuantity').val(quantatyNumber);
        alert("quantety = " + quantety + " quantetyNumber = "+ quantatyNumber);
               var summaplus = wrapper.find('.inputQuantity').attr('id');
               var totalPlus = wrapper.find('.pengerpenger').text();
               alert('pengerpenger = '+ totalPlus);
               totalPlus = parseInt(totalPlus);
               summaplus = parseInt(summaplus);
               alert(totalPlus + " " + summaplus);
               var total = totalPlus + summaplus;
               alert(total);
               wrapper.filters('.pengerpenger').text(total);

               var summaUp = $('.summa').text();
                    summaUp = parseInt(summaUp);
                    var Plus = summaUp + summaplus;
                    $('.Geld').text(Plus);
                    $('.summa').text(Plus);
                }else{
                    $('.inputQuantity').val(1);
                }
    });

    $('.qantetyImgMinus').on('click', function(){
        var wrapperMinus = $(this).closest(".basDiv");
        quantetyMinus = wrapperMinus.find('.inputQuantity').val();
        alert('test');
        if(quantetyMinus >= 2){
            var quantatyNumber = quantetyMinus - 1;
            $('.inputQuantity').val(quantatyNumber);
               var summaminus = wrapperMinus.find('.inputQuantity').attr('id');
               var totalMinus = wrapperMinus.find('.pengerpenger').text();
               totalMinus = parseInt(totalMinus);
               summaminus = parseInt(summaminus);
               var Minus = totalMinus - summaminus;
               alert(Minus);
               wrapperMinus.filter('.pengerpenger').text(Minus);
               //
               var summaDown = $('.summa').text();
                    summaDown = parseInt(summaDown);
                    var total = summaDown - summaminus;
                    $('.Geld').text(total);
                    $('.summa').text(total);
        }else if(quantetyMinus === 1){
            $('.inputQuantity').val(1);
        }
    });
```

But now if I click on Plus image it works fine it change total price as it have to do, but it change price for all span with class name "pengerpenger"  and I need only for this with is in the same div block with class name "basDiv" and it change the value of all input box.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed if same body need code

```
 $('.qantetyImgPlus').on('click', function(){
    var wrapper = $(this).closest(".basDiv");
        quantety = wrapper.find('.inputQuantity').val();
        quantety = parseInt(quantety);
        if(quantety >= 1){
            var quantatyNumber = quantety + 1;
            wrapper.find('.inputQuantity').val(quantatyNumber);
               var summaplus = wrapper.find('.inputQuantity').attr('id');
               var totalPlus = wrapper.find('.pengerpenger').text();
               totalPlus = parseInt(totalPlus);
               summaplus = parseInt(summaplus);
               var total = totalPlus + summaplus;
               wrapper.find('.pengerpenger').text(total);

               var summaUp = $('.summa').text();
                    summaUp = parseInt(summaUp);
                    var Plus = summaUp + summaplus;
                    $('.Geld').text(Plus);
                    $('.summa').text(Plus);
                }
    });

    $('.qantetyImgMinus').on('click', function(){
        var wrapperMinus = $(this).closest(".basDiv");
        quantetyMinus = wrapperMinus.find('.inputQuantity').val();
        quantetyMinus = parseInt(quantetyMinus);
        if(quantetyMinus >= 2){
            var quantatyNumber = quantetyMinus - 1;
            wrapperMinus.find('.inputQuantity').val(quantatyNumber);
               var summaminus = wrapperMinus.find('.inputQuantity').attr('id');
               var totalMinus = wrapperMinus.find('.pengerpenger').text();
               totalMinus = parseInt(totalMinus);
               summaminus = parseInt(summaminus);
               var Minus = totalMinus - summaminus;
               wrapperMinus.find('.pengerpenger').text(Minus);
               //
               var summaDown = $('.summa').text();
                    summaDown = parseInt(summaDown);
                    var total = summaDown - summaminus;
                    $('.Geld').text(total);
                    $('.summa').text(total);
        }else if(quantetyMinus === 1){

        }
    });
```